# How to connect to SOLR Cloud Cluster in a Zookeeper Ensemble via PHP

Tags: php, solr, apache-zookeeper, solarium

we are trying to connect to a solr 8.11 Cluster which is handled by a zookeeper ensemble from a php application.

we can't absolutly no documentation for solarium how we can connect to a solr cloud cluster, but we found things like this
https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/blob/db95226bb49d43d082eccedd1ce53e8098fc54d8/tests/Integration/Fixtures/docker/solr9_cloud/docker-compose.yml (basically exactly our setup, 3 solr nodes, 3 zookeeper nodes) but we cant find a test where this cluster is used.

we just find some hints, like this:

```
protected static function createTechproducts(): void
{
    self::$config = [
        'endpoint' => [
            'localhost' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 8983,
                'path' => '/',
                'collection' => self::$name,
                'username' => 'solr',
                'password' => 'SolrRocks',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/blob/master/tests/Integration/AbstractCloudTest.php

so endpoint seems to be an array and we could add more hosts there, but why it connects to the solr port instead of the zookeeper port?

we also can't find issues, problems or stackoverflow threads regarding utilizing a solr cloud cluster with zookeeper via php.

what we found was a completly outdated libary, https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium-cloud which is not active in development and which even never has gotten production ready

so basically the simple question is, How to connect to solrcloud cluster with 3 solr nodes and 3 zookeeper nodes from php?